# Mongoose "ref" documentation, cannot find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have spent the last half and hour trying to find documentation on the ref property when defining a Mongoose schema. I can't find it!

```
branch: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Branch' // <--- Where is the documentation for this property
}
```

Can someone by my hero and link where it is.

I've tried the following: http://mongoosejs.com/index.html and choose "read the docs", nada. :(

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: It's just a definition of property having nested document

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) is the only place I could find a reference to `ref` in the documentation. In short, `ref` is used to let mongoose know what model to populate when you use something like [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate).

For example, let's assume the name of your model is `Tree`. If you wanted to find all of the trees and also populate all of the information for each `branch` associated with each `tree` you would use the following code:

```
Tree
  .find({})
  //note that this is lowercase branch
  .populate('branch')
  .exec((err,trees) => {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(trees);
   });
```